# How do I define empty datetime in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't define empty datetime in dart. And I don't know the answer to this question

I looked on the internet but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be better make it null-able .

```
DateTime? date;
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Empty != null. How do I define `empty string` in dart? I think it would be better make it `null-able`. I don't think this is correct.

Comment: @mezoni As I've mentioned *I think*, You cant make dateTime empty, it will get some value(as you can see your ans) and  `String` & `DateTime` are  different. more on [DateTime](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime emptyDateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0);
```

outputs the value :

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way. First second of our era.

```dart
final date = DateTime(1);
print(date);
```

Output:

`0001-01-01 00:00:00.000`